# Using qm (qemu) output in a script

Tags: bash, qemu

I am trying to determine if a QEMU VM has finished booting from inside a script by using QEMU agent.

The problem is that I am unable to assign the output to a variable or even pipe it to a file:

```
[root@node1 dir]# isrunning=$(qm agent 1234 ping)
VM 1234 is not running
[root@node1 dir]# echo $isrunning

[root@node1 dir]# isrunning=`qm agent 1234 ping`
VM 1234 is not running
[root@node1 dir]# echo $isrunning

[root@node1 dir]# qm agent 1234 ping > /tmp/qmclonevm
VM 1234 is not running
[root@node1 dir]# echo /tmp/qmclonevm 
/tmp/qmclonevm
[root@node1 dir]# qm agent 1234 ping | tee /tmp/qmclonevm
VM 1234 is not running
[root@node1 dir]# cat /tmp/qmclonevm 
[root@node1 dir]#
```

I assumed that qm would simply print to stdout like usual, it seems like this is not the case.

Does anyone know what is going on here and how to work around that problem or can anyone provide a different solution to check if a VM is fully booted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ping
```

with

```
ping 2>&1
```

to redirect qm's stderr to stdout.